# Can I group tabs from the same site into one parent tab in Safari?

Tags: safari, browser-tabs

I'd like to have all tabs of a single website grouped into a parent tab, so that they have a  hierarchical structure. Graphically, just a drop down would be good. Does it exist? I use Safari on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 0):

You can group multiple tabs in new Safari windows:

```
File > New Window
```

You can actually drag tabs from one Safari window into another Safari window (into the "tab" area of the window).

(I can do this on OSX 10.4 Tiger)